# listener for Tapping on a Tab Navigator Icon not working

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm implementing tap to scroll to top, when one of the bottom tab navigator is tapped. I added a listener to know hen it's tapped but its not working.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('Tapped');
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Im getting `Tapped` in logges when I switch to another tab and then go back to the same tab. Does anyone have a solution on how to fix this ?

P.S: I tried `scrollToTop` hook but its not working for some reason

Comment: Hello, have you tried wrapping your screen in a `ScrollView` and using the `scrollTo` method?
 https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto

Comment: Hey, yes I tried but the problem is I want to press the Tab icon to scroll up. and I can't manage to do that